# Can i use _addItem before _addTrans in tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i must inclure Tracking Code for Ecommerce into existing code .
I know I should use these methods `_addItem` , `_addTrans` , `_trackTrans` .

can i use this code :

`

```
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

_gaq.push(['_addItem',
   '1234',          
   'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
   'T-Shirt',        // product name
   'Olive Medium',   // category or variation
   '11.99',          // unit price - required
   '1'               // quantity - required
]);

_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
  '1234',           // transaction ID - required
  'Womens Apparel', // affiliation or store name
  '28.28',          // total - required
  '1.29',           // tax
  '15.00',          // shipping
  'San Jose',       // city
  'California',     // state or province
  'USA'             // country
]);

_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
```

`

or it's mandatory to use `_addTrans` before `_addItem`

thank

Comment: Have you tested it? Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can do this, the item will not be associated to the transaction. If you call _addItem first without a transaction, the item will be associated to an empty transaction and reports will be shown by SKU.

Read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addItem for more details...